# How can I tell when my query should be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

I've seen many questions asking how users can optimize their queries because they're too slow, even when they last less than a second. Trying to understand what defines a slow query, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628211/what-is-considered-slow-with-respect-to-sql-queries) that says it's anything the user complains about.

This makes sense, but it's not fool proof. A poor non-optimized query could go unnoticed if the front end user doesn't know any better. I also understand that the speed of a query can change depending on context.

Is there a rule of thumb for query speed? For example, let's say I can query a trillion records in 50 ms (made up number), but I have another query that takes 50ms to only query 100 records. Clearly one is inneficient, but both are the same to a front-end user. Is there something similar to Big-O notation that can be applied to SQL queries?

Answer (score 5):

Optimization should be based on user requirements for data access, not on abstract notions of what seems good or not.

In my opinion, for an on-going application, you should first write your queries for maintenance purposes -- how will you fix, maintain, and understand the code 6 months from now?  2 years from now?  If you can't maintain the code, then optimization is an on-going nightmare.  I'm not advocating writing inefficient code, and there are definitely some best/better practices in terms of performance (such as avoiding unnecessary materialized subqueries in MySQL).  But understanding what is happening tends to be more important in the long-term than optimizations that may no longer be necessary with the next software path.  Some techniques for optimizing queries are likely to directly conflict with this goal.  Many others are going to support it well.

Second, when performance does start to degrade, you have to decide the balance between investing in more or better hardware and changing the software.  Some changes, such as adding appropriate indexes or partitioning large tables may be quite desirable, regardless.  Other changes, such as creating summary tables maintained by triggers add complexity and may be less desirable.

In short, performance is there is meet user requirements.  If your system is meeting those requirements, you can worry about other things.  If you have nothing to worry about,

Comment: So in the example of the 50ms for a million records or 100 records, if all else were equal and both maintainable would you say both are fine? That it doesn't matter if one is 20k records per millisecond when the other is only 2 records per millisecond, so long as it doesn't hurt the user and both are maintainable?

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . First, write reasonable, maintainable code.  Then, if you need to optimize, optimize.  But that should be driven by user requirements.  If there is no performance bottleneck, there are usually other things to work on.